# Got an error once installed the program in computer

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I already created an application with the function that could view the database through that application. When on the Visual Studio 2010 (Haven't released yet), the application that I made run smoothly and no error found. But, when I released it and made a Set-up and install it on my computer and when I run the program and click the view database, it gave the error "**Object reference not set to an instance of an object**, but when I check back in the Visual Studio 2010, the error didn't appear and run smoothly. Just when I install the application, the error appears.

This is the error that I am getting when run the application through installed program, not through Visual Studio 2010 (Debugging):

[image]

When I click "**Continue**", the program run as it is and run smoothly, I just wondering why this error appears only at the installed program, not in the debugging.

Anyone know how would that happen?

Here is the details:

[image]

Comment: Read the stack trace (Details)

Comment: I think it is better to to use try catch block for your application, coz obviously you are receiving this because in one of your object initiation or reference it throws a null reference which means you the object is null before even using it.

Comment: @mpakbaz Nope, it is not better. The right way is to initialize everything before using it. And exception-driven development is not a good approach

Comment: It would help to know what `Point_of_Sales__Special_.Trans.Trans_Load` contains. It seems like the obvious starting point for _debugging_ your application. Most likely the installed application doesn't have access to a resource that was available when run in design mode.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite likely that something got optimized away by the compiler when building in release mode, which can cause surprises at runtime. Perhaps one of your object is being initialized by a side-effect that the compiler "optimized away".

One easy way to try to get to the bottom of the problem is to wrap the call to the offending method in a try/catch, and when catching the exception, pop it up along with a full stack trace in a message box.  What you're interested in is the line number where the null reference exception is actually occurring.  Or better yet, write it out to a log file with any additional information you would like to know about at runtime.  Then, redeploy your application, reinstall it, and give it another go. Once you figure out which object is not being initialized, then you will want to analyze your code to see why that would happen only in release builds and not in debug builds.  You should look to see if you're using some sort of pattern (or anti-pattern) where it could affect other places in your code.